# Different connection exceptions in Redis

Tags: java, multithreading, redis, jedis

I am using Redis in server mode and not in Cluster mode. I have 3 instances of Redis Server running, 3 slaves corresponding to these 3 masters. I also have 3 Sentinels each monitoring all the three masters.

To connect to my Sentinels and create a pool, I am using [ShardedJedisSentinelPool](https://github.com/warmbreeze/sharded-jedis-sentinel-pool/blob/master/src/main/java/redis/clients/jedis/ShardedJedisSentinelPool.java). Now my class to get connection from this pool looks like this

```
public class RedisServerConnectionDAL 
{
    private RedisServerConnectionDAL()
    {

    }

    private static ShardedJedisSentinelPool pool;
    private static ShardedJedis jedis;
    private static ShardedJedisPipeline pipeline;
    private static Set<String> redissentinels;
    private static List<String> redismasters;
    private static int redistimeout;
    private static RedisServerConnectionDAL redisdal;
    private static Map<String,String> redisconfmap;
    public static int WAIT_IF_FAIL;
    public static int RETRIES;

    public synchronized static RedisServerConnectionDAL getInstance()
    {
         if(redisdal==null)
         {
             Properties redisprops = new Properties();

             redisprops = ConfigReader.ReadConfig(Constant.REDIS_CONNECTION_CONFIG_FILE);

             GenericObjectPoolConfig config = new GenericObjectPoolConfig();

             redisconfmap = new HashMap(redisprops);

             redisdal = new RedisServerConnectionDAL();

             String redisNodesString = redisconfmap.get(Constant.REDIS_SENTINELS);

             redissentinels = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(redisNodesString.split(Constant.CONFIGURATION_FILE_MULTIVALUE_SEPERATOR)));

             String redisMastersString = redisconfmap.get(Constant.REDIS_MASTERS);

             redismasters = new ArrayList<String>();

             redismasters.addAll(Arrays.asList(redisMastersString.split(Constant.CONFIGURATION_FILE_MULTIVALUE_SEPERATOR)));

             redistimeout = Integer.parseInt(redisconfmap.get(Constant.REDIS_TIMEOUT));

             WAIT_IF_FAIL = Integer.parseInt(redisconfmap.get(Constant.REDIS_WAIT_IF_FAIL));

             RETRIES = Integer.parseInt(redisconfmap.get(Constant.REDIS_RETRIES));

             pool = new ShardedJedisSentinelPool(redismasters, redissentinels, config, redistimeout);

             jedis = pool.getResource();

             pipeline = jedis.pipelined();

         }
         return redisdal;
    }

    public ShardedJedis getJedisResource()
    {
        jedis = pool.getResource();
        return jedis;
    }

    public ShardedJedisPipeline getPipelineResource()
    {
        pipeline = jedis.pipelined();
        return pipeline;
    }

    public ShardedJedisPipeline getPipeline()
    {
        return pipeline;
    }

    public ShardedJedis getJedis()
    {
        return jedis;
    }

    public static void resetRedisServerConnectionDal()
    {
        pipeline = null;
        jedis = null;
        redisdal = null;
    }
}
```

So, now whereever I want to interact with Redis, I do something like this

```
Jedis jedis = RedisServerConnectionDAL.getInstance.getJedis();

try
{
    //code.....
}
catch(JedisConnectionException jce)
{
        log.error(jce.getMessage());
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
        jce.printStackTrace(pw);
        log.error("Error:" + sw.toString());
        if(retrycount < RedisServerConnectionDAL.RETRIES)
        {
            retrycount++;
            log.error("Waiting for " + RedisServerConnectionDAL.WAIT_IF_FAIL + ", after which it will reconnect to Redis.");
            try 
            {
                Thread.sleep(RedisServerConnectionDAL.WAIT_IF_FAIL);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) 
            {
                log.error(e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace(pw);
                log.error("Error:" + sw.toString());
                log.error("Error while Sleeing!!!");
            }
            RedisServerConnectionDAL.resetRedisServerConnectionDal();

            jedis = RedisServerConnectionDAL.getInstance();.getJedisResource();
            pipeline = redisserverconnectiondal.getPipelineResource();
        }
        else
        {
            log.error("Redis retries exhausted");
            log.error(jce.getMessage());
            StringWriter sw1 = new StringWriter();
            PrintWriter pw1 = new PrintWriter(sw1);
            jce.printStackTrace(pw1);
            log.error("Error:" + sw1.toString());
            log.error("Error while executing pipeline in Redis!");
            retrycount = 0;;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        log.error(e.getMessage());
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
        e.printStackTrace(pw);
        log.error("Error:" + sw.toString());
        log.error("Error while executing pipeline in Redis!");
    }
```

But I am continuously getting exceptions like Connection refused exception, Connection closed exception.

Sometime I also get Null pointer exception in catch block at line

```
jedis = RedisServerConnectionDAL.getInstance();.getJedisResource();
```

A typical log for exception looks like

```
ERROR  com.cleartrail.entityprofiling.rediscachecomponent.InMemoryDataAccessLayer -     Error:redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.sendCommand(Protocol.java:94)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.sendCommand(Protocol.java:74)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.sendCommand(Connection.java:78)
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.hexists(BinaryClient.java:257)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Client.hexists(Client.java:174)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Jedis.hexists(Jedis.java:705)
    at redis.clients.jedis.ShardedJedis.hexists(ShardedJedis.java:213)
    at com.cleartrail.entityprofiling.rediscachecomponent.InMemoryDataAccessLayer.checkForNewEntity(InMemoryDataAccessLayer.java:339)
    at com.cleartrail.entityprofiling.rediscachecomponent.InMemoryDataAccessLayer.writeInMemoryData(InMemoryDataAccessLayer.java:215)
    at com.cleartrail.entityprofiling.rediscachecomponent.InMemoryDataAccessLayer.run(InMemoryDataAccessLayer.java:715)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:113)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
    at redis.clients.util.RedisOutputStream.flushBuffer(RedisOutputStream.java:31)
    at redis.clients.util.RedisOutputStream.writeIntCrLf(RedisOutputStream.java:186)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.sendCommand(Protocol.java:81)
    ... 10 more
```

I know I am not using the connection pool in right manner. Please suggest the proper way to do it. Also, I am using jedis is multithreaded environment where two threads will call RedisServerConnectionDAL.getInstance().getJedisResource() method and interact with Redis. Is Jedis thread safe?

Answer (score 0):

Jedis instances are not thread-safe, but you can use the `JedisPool` to obtain a connection per thread and to ensure you get a working connection from the pool.

The [lettuce client](https://github.com/mp911de/lettuce) is thread-safe and manages auto-reconnects for you. You won't see any exceptions in your code due to reconnects/connection resets. lettuce also works with Redis Sentinel.